# Why HERE API reponds with empty "View" on valid url request?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, here-api, spring-ws

I'm trying to call HERE geocoder API, but on a valid url call the response body isn't fully initialized.

As shown below, I simply call a the API providing a valid url:

```
val url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(properties.geocodeUrl)
    .queryParam("app_id", properties.appId)
    .queryParam("app_code", properties.appCode)
    .queryParam("searchtext", "10 Downing Street, London")
    .toUriString()

logger.debug("calling geocoder rest service: $url")

val geocoderResponse = RestTemplate().getForObject<GeocoderResponse>(url)
```

**GeocoderResponse**

```
package com.gudjob.geolocation

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.gudjob.core.domain.Coordinates
import java.io.Serializable

/**
 * @author Elia Sgolmin
 */
internal data class GeocoderResponse(
    @field:JsonProperty("Response")
    var response: Response?
) : Serializable {

    data class Response(
        @field:JsonProperty("View")
        var views: List<View>
    ) : Serializable {

        data class View(
            @field:JsonProperty("Result")
            var results: List<Result>
        ) : Serializable {

            data class Result(
                @field:JsonProperty("Location")
                var location: Location?
            ) : Serializable {

                data class Location(
                    @field:JsonProperty("DisplayPosition")
                    var displayPosition: DisplayPosition?
                ) : Serializable {

                    data class DisplayPosition(
                        @field:JsonProperty("Latitude")
                        var latitude: Double?,

                        @field:JsonProperty("Longitude")
                        var longitude: Double?
                    ) : Serializable {

                        fun toCoordinates(): Coordinates {
                            val lat = latitude
                            val lon = longitude
                            return if (lat == null || lat.isNaN() || lon == null || lon.isNaN())
                                Coordinates.Unavailable
                            else
                                Coordinates.Available(lat, lon)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I copy the logged url and use it in browser or postman I get the following **expected** response

```js
{  
   "Response":{  
      "MetaInfo":{  
         "Timestamp":"2019-02-26T14:03:09.236+0000"
      },
      "View":[  
         {  
            "_type":"SearchResultsViewType",
            "ViewId":0,
            "Result":[  
               {  
                  "Relevance":1,
                  "MatchLevel":"houseNumber",
                  "MatchQuality":{  
                     "City":1,
                     "Street":[  
                        1
                     ],
                     "HouseNumber":1
                  },
                  "MatchType":"pointAddress",
                  "Location":{  
                     "LocationId":"NT_lWsc8knsFwVitNTFX88zmA_xAD",
                     "LocationType":"point",
                     "DisplayPosition":{  
                        "Latitude":51.50341,
                        "Longitude":-0.12765
                     },
                     "NavigationPosition":[  
                        {  
                           "Latitude":51.50322,
                           "Longitude":-0.12767
                        }
                     ],
                     "MapView":{  
                        "TopLeft":{  
                           "Latitude":51.5045342,
                           "Longitude":-0.129456
                        },
                        "BottomRight":{  
                           "Latitude":51.5022858,
                           "Longitude":-0.125844
                        }
                     },
                     "Address":{  
                        "Label":"10 Downing Street, London, SW1A 2AA, United Kingdom",
                        "Country":"GBR",
                        "State":"England",
                        "County":"London",
                        "City":"London",
                        "District":"Westminster",
                        "Street":"Downing Street",
                        "HouseNumber":"10",
                        "PostalCode":"SW1A 2AA",
                        "AdditionalData":[  
                           {  
                              "value":"United Kingdom",
                              "key":"CountryName"
                           },
                           {  
                              "value":"England",
                              "key":"StateName"
                           },
                           {  
                              "value":"London",
                              "key":"CountyName"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, "View" attribute of "Response" object is an array with one object containing latitude and longitude of the given address.

What I get instead is

> GeocoderResponse(response = Response(views = []))

where `response` has been initialized, but `views` is empty.

Changing my code to get JSON response as plain text with

```java
restTemplate().getForObject<String>(url)
```

it results in the following json

> {"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2019-02-26T13:35:37.851+0000"},"View":[]}}

Even here `"View"` property is empty so I don't think the issue is about JSON deserialization.

Any suggestion?

## UPDATE

I've checked `RestTemplate` request headers vs. browsers and postman ones, but couldn't find any relevant difference.

The only think I can point out is postman **response** header *Content-Encoding → gzip*, which is missing in Spring response.

Comment: Maybe response from server depends from [`Content Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type) or some other headers? Play with `postman` and try to find why it returns other response. Do you have an access to `REST` `API` method implementation you invoke?

Comment: There is no Content-Type since [Here's geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/what-is.html) uses url parameters.
The only header restTemplate adds is `Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]`. Giving this parameter to postman doen't change its (correct) response. About response headers, postman gets an additional one: `Content-Encoding → gzip` (and of course `Content

Comment: If you are sure everything is the same, you can do a `Unit Test` where you try to deserialise example response to object using `ObjectMapper`. It will prove that `POJO` structure fits `JSON` payload.

Comment: As I stated in my update, if I ask the response as a String, rest API responds with the quoted string and `View` is already empty, so I don't think it's a POJO problem

Comment: Try GSON, I tried it with GSON. It works perfectly.

Comment: @Moinkhan the issue is **not** about jackson vs. gson or others since even getting the body as a string I get empty `View`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be ,the query parameter searchtext is not being URL encoded when requesting via the UriComponentsBuilder interface. Try encoding the string being passed and check the response.

```
.queryParam("searchtext", URLEncoder.encode("10 Downing Street, London","UTF-8"))
```